# Is it possible to use sysout without class and main method in Eclipse IDE using Java 9?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, jshell

As Java 9 introduced the concept of JShell which enables us to write code without creating a class and a method, is it possible to use this feature of Java 9 in eclipse ?

Comment: you can wait for Eclipse support for JShell. But if you want to do it without JShell- then you cannot

Comment: Why has been my question downvoted ? Please let me know so that I can improve my question in future

Comment: it´s a very generic/basic/.. question and Stackoverflow is for solving code-issues with some example code.

Comment: And here is a [how-to-jshell-eclipse](https://kichwacoders.com/2017/05/25/woohoo-java-9-has-a-repl-getting-started-with-jshell-and-eclipse-january/) for you.

Comment: There is Eclipse’s [Scrapbook](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cscrapbook.htm) feature for eons now. I really don’t understand the big fuzz about JShell…

Comment: @Holger, with a well-integrated jshell in some IDE of your choice you can easily use and script your own custom classes and libraries. I guess that is appealing to those praising jshell. I. e. with Intellij it is just: Add target folder of your project to libraries once, run jshell, put in some code, hit one key comb et voilá.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [***TM Terminal***](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) to run JShell in Eclipse:

- If necessary, install [***TM Terminal***](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) (contained only in some Eclipse packages)
- Open a 'Terminal' view in Eclipse: ***Window > Show View > Other...: Terminal > Terminal***
- **Launch a new *Local Terminal***
- **Run JShell, e. g. on Windows type `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\jshell" -v`** followed by **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can use a [***Scrapbook Page***](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-15.htm), a built-in feature of the Eclipse Java IDE and which also works with older Java versions. You will have code completion and you can use Java classes of your project:

[image]

Comment: You should probably format your answer better, as it's hard to read it. Thanks.

Comment: @DawidZbiński Is it so okay?

Comment: I managed to run the jshell from the terminal, but I dont want to do this all the time. How can I create a menu to make all those steps automatically and save me time?

Answer (score 4):

If this is not a feature ask for Eclipse, a very basic stub that you can come up with is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     jdk.jshell.tool.JavaShellToolBuilder.builder().run();
}
```

When you execute this, you can further use your debug console as JShell in your IDE.

***Sample screenshot***:
[image]

Comment: When I write System.out.print("Hello"); and press Enter, the cursor keeps on blinking in the next line, it doesn't give any output. If I do the same thing in cmd prompt I get the output "Hello" in the next line. Why is the behavior different and how to execute jshell code in eclipse ?

Comment: No output printing for me in Eclipse. The cursor keeps on blinking in the next line. I am using latest Oxygen version. I suppose you are using a different editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use JShell (from Eclipse or from a Terminal) to try out code, a very nice option is to use the Maven JShell plugin and just run mvn from a corresponding (dummy) project (in Eclipse: Right-Click on the Project and Run As -> Maven build).

In that case JShell knows all the libraries specified in the dependencies of the project.

I am use this here: http://www.finmath.net/finmath-experiments/montecarlo-blackscholes/

A small pom.xml using some libraries (JavaFX, Apache commons, finmath lib) could look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.finmath</groupId>
    <artifactId>finmath-experiments</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean install jshell:run</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.johnpoth</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jshell-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Java FX -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- finmath-lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.finmath</groupId>
            <artifactId>finmath-lib</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.finmath</groupId>
            <artifactId>finmath-lib-plot-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Note: Personally I prefer running this from a Terminal in macOS, since JShell supports "TAB-auto-completion" there, which appears to be missing when running from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this as explained in other answers. But I would like to tell you a plugin which will provide more feature than just starting a normal JShell from Eclipse.

Check this Eclipse plugin [QuickShell](https://github.com/nileshkhaire/QuickShell)

This plugin will start JShell in Eclipse terminal. Like this:

[image: Quick Shell Terminal]

You can also select your existing java source code and run it as a JShell script. For example :

[image: Quick Shell Execute as script]

.jsh and .jpage files can be run from Eclipse directly.

[image: Run JSh and jpage file]

PS: I am author of this plugin.