# How to integrate jshell with Spring Tool Suite or STS?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, java-9, jshell

I have a project using the Jdk 9 library in STS or Spring Tool suite.

Now what do i need to do to integrate or work with jshell from within the STS/eclipe?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something alike - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705036/in-jshell-how-to-import-classpath-from-a-maven-project && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805687/is-it-possible-to-use-sysout-without-class-and-main-method-in-eclipse-ide-using. Please, do detail out if you mean something different.